# Get UIImage only with Kingfisher library

Tags: ios, swift2, uiimage, kingfisher

I need to get a UIImage only instead of loading a normal UIImageView with [Kingfisher library](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

To realize it I implemented a workaround with UIImageView:

```
let imageView = UIImageView()

imageView.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: cpa.imageName)!, placeholderImage: nil,
        optionsInfo: [.Transition(ImageTransition.Fade(1))],
        progressBlock: { receivedSize, totalSize in
            print("\(receivedSize)/\(totalSize)")
        },
        completionHandler: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
            anView!.image = image //anView IS NOT an UIImageView
            anView!.frame.size = CGSize(width: 15.0, height: 15.0)
            print("Finished")
    })
```

This code works perfectly, but I would like to do it in a cleaner way.
Is there a method in this library to get an UIImage only? Async and cached

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You could use the `retrieveImage(with:options:progressBlock: completionHandler:)` method of `KingfisherManager` for this.

Maybe something like this:

```
KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: url, options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
    print(image)
})
```

Comment: Annoyingly renamed in Swift 3 to  `KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: url!, options: nil, progressBlock: nil)  { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> () in
            print(image)
        }`

Comment: Does this also cache the image?

Comment: @DoesData yes it does

Comment: @DmitrijRogov Does you need to do anything to store the image in cache?

Comment: is it cache in memory or disk ?

Comment: this is old syntax, update the answer to say it explicitly.

Answer (score 49):

**This is latest syntax to download image in kingFisher 5 (Tested in swift 4.2)**

```
func downloadImage(`with` urlString : String){
    guard let url = URL.init(string: urlString) else {
        return
    }
    let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: url)

    KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: resource, options: nil, progressBlock: nil) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let value):
            print("Image: \(value.image). Got from: \(value.cacheType)")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

**How to call above function**

```
self.downloadImage(with: imageURL) //replace with your image url
```

Comment: resource is a URL("url-string") object, so for anyone coming from another language it is not clear. Also, you could remove parameters where you send nil, and you could remove the completion hanlder when you don't care about the image don't loading.

Answer (score 12):

With the new Swift 3 version you can use ImageDownloader :

```
ImageDownloader.default.downloadImage(with: url, options: [], progressBlock: nil) {
    (image, error, url, data) in
    print("Downloaded Image: \(image)")
}
```

`ImageDownloader` is a part of Kingfisher so don't forget to `import Kingfisher`.

Comment: This would not leverage the cache as per this [line](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/blob/743e3f2a54408de212d8ec74a5c91747b6a26f7e/Sources/ImageDownloader.swift#L288)  `cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` which is the point of using Kinfisher over any other simpler method

Answer (score 10):

Swift 5:

I will complete on **@Hardik Thakkar** answer to add a change so that you can **return** the image using a closure may that helps somebody:

```
func downloadImage(with urlString : String , imageCompletionHandler: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void){
        guard let url = URL.init(string: urlString) else {
            return  imageCompletionHandler(nil)
        }
        let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: url)
        
        KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: resource, options: nil, progressBlock: nil) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let value):
                imageCompletionHandler(value.image)
            case .failure:
                imageCompletionHandler(nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

How to call:

```
 downloadImage(with :yourUrl){image in
     guard let image  = image else { return}
      // do what you need with the returned image.
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

In Kingfisher 5

```
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url) { result in
   switch result {
   case .success(let value):
       print("Image: \(value.image). Got from: \(value.cacheType)")
   case .failure(let error):
       print("Error: \(error)")
   }
 }
```

see more: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Kingfisher-5.0-Migration-Guide

Answer (score 6):

Another way in Kingfisher 5:

```
KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: url) { result in
    let image = try? result.get().image
    if let image = image {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I get No exact matches in call to instance method 'retrieveImage' when using this function

Answer (score 6):

Swift 5
Kingfisher 5

This code is 100% working

```
YourImageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: imagePath), placeholder: nil, options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { result in
switch result {
    case .success(let value):
                print("Image: \(value.image). Got from: \(value.cacheType)")
    case .failure(let error):
                print("Error: \(error)")
    }
})

//OR
let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: picUrl!)
KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: resource, options: nil, progressBlock: nil) { result in
    switch result {
        case .success(let value):
        print("Image: \(value.image). Got from: \(value.cacheType)")
        imageProfile = value.image
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to custom UILabel instated of UIImageView from api call.

```swift
import Kingfisher
```

```swift
func getImage(imageUrl: String,title:String?=nil){

        let someTitle = UILabel()
        view.addSubview(someTitle)
        someTitle.text = title
        someTitle.isHidden = true
       
        someTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        someTitle.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        someTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        someTitle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { [self] in
            let url = URL(string: imageUrl )
            yourImage.kf.setImage(
                with: url,
                placeholder:  (someTitle as? Placeholder),
                options: [
                    .loadDiskFileSynchronously,
                    .cacheOriginalImage,
                    .transition(.fade(0.25))
                ],
                completionHandler: { result in
                    // Done
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let value):
                         self.yourImage.image = value.image
                    case .failure(let error):
                        someTitle.isHidden = false
                    }
                }
            )
                        
        }
    }
```

**Just call the function in your Controller**

```swift
getImage(imageUrl: you_url, title: your_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a custom UIImage and UIImageView

```
let url = URL(string: "https://iosacademy.io/assets/images/brand/icon.jpg")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addPicture()
    
}

private func addPicture() {
    let containerView = UIView()
    //let myImage = UIImage(named: "Old Scroll Lengmei") // to add UIImage  by code
    let myImage = UIImage()
    let myImageView = UIImageView() // to add UIImageView by code
    let label = UILabel() // to add Label by code
    
    myImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kingfisher  7.11.0 +

```
imageViewIcon.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: nil, options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { response in
    if let image = try? response.get().image {
        imageViewIcon.image = image
    }
    else {
      // imageViewIcon.image = UIImage.init(named: "user")
     }
 })
```